# Is it possible to split request params in Spring controllers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a request like:

```
example.com/search?sort=myfield1,-myfield2,myfield3
```

I would like to split those params to bind a `List<String>` sort in my controller or `List<SortParam>` where `SortParam` is the class with fields like: `name` (String) and `ask` (boolean).

So the final controller would look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> search(@RequestParam List<String> sort) {

    //...
}
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> search(@RequestParam List<SortParam> sort) {

    //...
}
```

Is there a way to make it?

**UPDATE:**

The standard way of passing parameters does not satisfy my requirements. I.e. I cannot use `sort=myfield1&sort=-myfield2&sort=myfield3`. I have to use comma separated names.
Also, I do understand that I can accept `@RequestParam String sort` in my controller and then split the string inside the controller like `sort.split(",")` but it also doesn't solve the above problem.

Comment: The correct, standard way to do this would be to use `/search?sort=myfield1&sort=-myfield2&sort=myfield3`. But splitting on a comma isn't such a hard task either.

Comment: Yes, splitting by comma isn't hard. I.e. just `str.split(",")` but I wonder if I can split such parameters before they arrive in the controller (not in the controller).

Comment: I would like to use `List<String> sort` in my controller, but the standard way of passing parameters does not satisfy my requirements. I have to use comma separated names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly do that, you're almost there.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> participants(@RequestParam("sort") List<String> sort) {

    //...
}
```

You should now be able to call your service like this (if search is located at your root, otherwise adapt according to your situation):

```
curl "localhost:8080/search?sort=sortField1&sort=sortField2&sort=sortField3"
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**
Sorry, I have read your comments and what you need is clear to me now. I have created a workaround for you that is almost what you want I think.

So first a SortParams class:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SortParams {
  private List<SortParam> sortParamList;

  public SortParams(String commaSeparatedString) {
    sortParamList = Arrays.stream(commaSeparatedString.split(","))
      .map(p -> SortParam.valueOf(p))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  public List<SortParam> getSortParamList() {
    return this.sortParamList;
  }

  public enum SortParam {
    FOO, BAR, FOOBAR;
  }
}
```

Then your controller could look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<SortParams.SortParam>> search(@RequestParam("sort") SortParams sort) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(sort.getSortParamList());
}
```

Now your SortParams object has a list of SortParam:

```
curl "localhost:8080/search?sort=FOO,BAR"

["FOO","BAR"]
```

Would something like this fit what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for helping, but this solution doesn't solve the above problem. Please check comments under the question. Also, I've updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I need!

Comment: The custom "SortParams" Type with converter logic in the constructor works just fine - but after that I saw the next answer and I think implementing that `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<Source, Target>` Interface is the cleaner approach. No need to call `.getSortParamList()` on that wrapper object but just directly get what you need in the controller.

Answer (score 7):

Its just a simple Type Covertion task. Spring defines an SPI (Service Provider Interface) to implement type conversion logic. For your specific problem you can define your Type Conversion logic by implementing `Converter` interface.

```
@Component
public class StringToListConverter implements Converter<String, List<String>> {

    @Override
    public List<String> convert(String source) {
        return Arrays.asList(source.split(","));
    }
}
```

You can also convert your request parameter to `List<SortPram>` according your logic (but I am not sure about your that logic from your question). This is it! Now Spring get known that how to bind your request paramter to a list.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> participants(@RequestParam("sort") List<String> sort) {
     // .. do your logic
}
```

There are many more ways to define you custom data binder. Check this

- [A Custom Data Binder in Spring MVC](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder) article.
- Spring documentation about [Validation, Data Binding, and Type Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I accepted the solution from Jonck van der Kogel but your solution is also great. Thanks.

Comment: This answer is the best one. It is much cleaner and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

It could be helpfull if Kotlin

```kotlin
private const val DELIMITER: Char = ':'
private val DEFAULT_DIRECTION: Sort.Direction = Sort.Direction.ASC

private fun parseFrom(source: String): Sort.Order = if (source.contains(DELIMITER)) {
    Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.fromString(source.substringAfter(DELIMITER)), source.substringBefore(DELIMITER))
} else Sort.Order(DEFAULT_DIRECTION, source)

// if few sort paremeters
@Component
class RequestSortConverterArray : Converter<Array<String>, Sort> {
    override fun convert(source: Array<String>): Sort? = if (source.isEmpty()) Sort.unsorted()
    else source.map { parseFrom(it) }.let { Sort.by(it) }
}

// if single sort paremeter
@Component
class RequestSortConverterString : Converter<String, Sort> {
    override fun convert(source: String): Sort? = if (source.isEmpty()) Sort.unsorted()
    else Sort.by(parseFrom(source))
}

...

@GetMapping
fun search(
  @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") page: Int,
  @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "20") size: Int,
  @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "myfield1:asc") sort: Sort
) {
  val pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, sort)
  // make a search by repository
}
```